# How can I change a channel name by x time, then return the name to the original one, and do a loop with that?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So how can I change a channel name by x time, then return the name to the original one, and do a loop with that? Please, show me an example. Thank you.

Comment: Please not that such actions can be considered API abuse https://imgur.com/enrhb2M

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of a channel, you have to use [`GuildChannel.setName()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=setName).
In order to do that in a loop, I'll use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

You can do something like this:

```js
// Assuming 'channel' is the channel you want to change
const altName = 'Your other channel name',
  originalName = channel.name,
  timer = 30000; // 30 seconds in this example (30*1000)

function change() {
  if (channel.name == originalName) channel.setName(altName);
  else channel.setName(originalName);
}

change();
const channelInterval = setInterval(change, timer);
```

It's up to you to decide whether to implement this in a command or when the bot starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `setTimeout` function. With this function you can pass a callback in the first parameter, and a time interval (in miliseconds) as the second parameter, that is the time it will delay to call your function. So it will be something like this:

```
function changeChannelName(name) {
  // Code to change channel name
}

setTimeout(changeChannelName, 10000, 'New channel name');
```

This way, after 10 seconds your function will be called. The third parameter of `setTimeout`, is your function parameter

Hope it helps you.